# chinese remainder theorem for gaussian integers

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem, gaussian-integers

I want to show that Chinese Remainder Theorem(CRT) has a unique solution over gaussian integers. But when I choose $x=4+5i$ and determine coprime modulo numbers $1+2i$ and $1+4i$, the simultaneous congruences

$4 + 5i \equiv  - 1\,\bmod (1 + 2i)$

$4 + 5i \equiv  - 1 + 2i\,\bmod (1 + 4i)$
is obtained. 
If I use CRT for modulo $1+2i$,$1+4i$ and remainders $-1$,$-1+2i$, I obtain
$ - 2 + 2i \ne 4 + 5i$.
What is the problem? When does a system have unique solution?

Comment: I think not many are going to be able to understand what you wrote. Somewhere in this place there's a guide how to write mathematics correctly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the CRT is not provided". Anyway, you know the solution of a system of congruences is not a single number, but a congruence class full of numbers, right?

Comment: I have edited my question. The right solution of question is $4+5i$, But  , when we use Chinese remainder theorem for remainder $-1,-1+2i $ and modulo $1+2i, 1+4i$, the solution is obtained $-2-2i$.

Comment: $-2-2i$ and $4+5i$ are both right, since $4+5i-(-2-2i)=6+7i$ is divisible by both $1+2i$ and $1+4i$, Indeed it is $-i(1+2i)(1+4i)

Comment: Why is the solution not unique? Nicolas

Comment: Ok I understand. Both are same in fact

Comment: This means that $-2-2i$ or $4+5i$ in $Z/(-6+7i)$. Is it right? Nicolas